# Dynamic pivot with Max(Date) from pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I want to keep this general so if it's ok, I'd prefer to not use my specific data set.

My general example:  I have a table of customers who have many orders.  I want a pivot table that shows how many orders each customer has had in each month (or general time frame).  Suppose I want to add a single column that shows the date for that customers most recent order.

So the table will look like:

```
CustomerID - January - February - March - April - May - MostRecentOrder
      0001 -       2 -        3 -     1 -     1 -   1 -      2013/5/18
      0002 -       1 -        0 -     1 -     0 -   1 -      2013/5/06
      0003 -       0 -        1 -     4 -     1 -   2 -      2013/5/11
      0004 -       2 -        0 -     0 -     1 -   0 -      2013/4/28
```

I tried to get a working sqlfiddle up at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbbad/1 but I'm apparently worse than I thought at Dynamic pivots in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include the most recent date for each customer, then you can use `max(orderdate) over(partition by customerId)`:

```
select customer.CustomerID, 
  o.OrderDate,
  max(o.orderdate) over(partition by customer.customerid) mostrecentorder
from Customers as customer
join Orders as o 
  on customer.CustomerID = o.customerid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbbad/24).

Your full code would be similar to:

```
declare @start DATE = '2012-01-01';
declare @end DATE = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE());

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

with months (dateList)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,dateList)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,dateList)<=@end
)
select dateList 
into #tempDates
from months
option (maxrecursion 0);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), datelist, 120)) 
                    from #tempDates
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = '
select *
from
(
  select customer.CustomerID, 
    o.OrderDate,
    max(o.orderdate) over(partition by customer.customerid) mostrecentorder
  from Customers as customer
  join Orders as o 
    on customer.CustomerID = o.customerid
) x
pivot
(
  Count(OrderDate)
  for OrderDate in ('+ @cols + ')
)y'

execute sp_executesql @query
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbbad/25).

If you want to show the data by month (which you are showing in your result above), then you can alter the code slightly to use [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx):

```
declare @start DATE = '2012-01-01';
declare @end DATE = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE());

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

with months (dateList)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,dateList)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,dateList)<=@end
)
select dateList 
into #tempDates
from months
option (maxrecursion 0);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(mth) 
                    from
                    (
                      select datepart(month, datelist) so, datename(month, datelist) mth
                      from #tempDates
                    ) d
                    group by so, mth
                    order by so, mth
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = '
select customerId, '+@cols+', mostrecentorder
from
(
  select customer.CustomerID, 
    datename(month, o.OrderDate) orderDate,
    max(o.orderdate) over(partition by customer.customerid) mostrecentorder
  from Customers as customer
  join Orders as o 
    on customer.CustomerID = o.customerid
) x
pivot
(
  Count(OrderDate)
  for OrderDate in ('+ @cols + ')
)y'

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbbad/28).  This will give a result:

```
| CUSTOMERID | JANUARY | FEBRUARY | MARCH | APRIL | MAY | JUNE | JULY | AUGUST | SEPTEMBER | OCTOBER | NOVEMBER | DECEMBER |            MOSTRECENTORDER |
|------------|---------|----------|-------|-------|-----|------|------|--------|-----------|---------|----------|----------|----------------------------|
|          3 |       1 |        1 |     1 |     1 |   1 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 | May, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|          2 |       1 |        1 |     1 |     1 |   1 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 | May, 13 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|          1 |       1 |        2 |     0 |     1 |   1 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 | May, 23 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```